# Actualizar length en columna JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy haciendo un login con springboot, al definir el length en la columna username para la entidad usuario inicialmente la puse como 20, luego al recapacitar que podemos tener usuarios con mayor cantidad de caracteres para username lo modifico para 200 caracteres, pero al levantar de nuevo el servidor JPA no actualiza la BD para y me sigue marcando el error que trunca esa columna por que es demasiado largo para la columna en la BD.

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, length =20)
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

modifico a

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, length =200)
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

pero la BD sigue igual, que la primera vez que se creo con JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Debes indicar en la configuración que se debe actualizar el esquema, busca el archivo `application.properties` y colocas:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Eso configura a hibernate para que haga la actualización del esquema.

Puedes leer más sobre la configuración en la documentación de spring:

[Spring Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization)

Comment: una disculpa no aclare que esa configuración ya la tengo,
en mi archivo application.properties tengo esto

spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update